# Loop table to even row amount in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loops, html-table

The question I have a table pulling from the backend for events, will list out in the font in 3 different column with specific categories, but sometimes only have 1 event or 2, but I need to at least display 3 items. 
So I try to use jQuery each function to check how many rows in the table if only have 1 add 2 rows if only have 1 row add 2 instead. 
So the table will be same height no matter how many events display.

My code doesn't work correctly, so I was hoping anyone can help me out with this.

Here's my sample code:http://jsfiddle.net/s2devfrg/

Here's the jQuery:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#table-amount tbody').each(function(){
        let number =jQuery(this).find('tr').length;
        console.log('amount' + number);
        //if table only have one add two extra row
        if(number === 1){
            jQuery(this).append("<tr>&nbsp;</tr>");
            jQuery(this).append("<tr>&nbsp;</tr>");
        } else {
         //if table only have two add one roe
           if(number === 2 ){
            jQuery(this).append("<tr>&nbsp;</tr>");
           }
        }

    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector you are using on `.each` is wrong. There are no elements with the passed id.

Also there are couple of blank `tr's` in your html which I have removed.

Try this code below:

```js
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(".table tbody").each(function(){
        let number =jQuery(this).find('tr').length;
        console.log('amount' + number);
        //if table only have one add two extra row
        if(number === 1){
            jQuery(this).append("<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr");

        } else if(number === 2 ){
             jQuery(this).append("<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>");
        }
    })
})
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <table class="table">
  <thead class="table-amount">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>

      
  </tbody>
</table>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col">
      <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col">
      <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Updated [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/s2devfrg/17/)

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score -3):

I have reviewed you sample code, first of all kindly note that in `jQuery`
when you find `tr` it will count total number of rows including `tr` inside thead. 
    So your 
    total counts are always one more than actual rows.
    Second thing you should not append just tr you should provide same structure 
    as in 
    your existing rows. 
    Also in first table structure you had one extra `th` may be typo.
    In first and third table structure you have one `tr` extra with empty 
    structure 
    instead, you should have same structure as you have for others.
    here is the link for modified JS Fiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/patelmurtuza/kj8zgqad/

Comment: Pranshu is correct if you change your selector instead of .table to jQuery(".table tbody") it will only count rows inside the tbody. its upto you you can use either way.

Comment: Did you really post your answer's content as code because Stack Overflow prevents you from adding JSFiddle links without some code? Please revise the answer and include relevant excerpts from the fiddle.

Comment: I am very new to stackoverflow to answer the question. Can sombody help me out with  guidelines to post the answer. I tried to put the code as well before providing the JS Fiddle link. But was not able to put it properly

Comment: Thanks maRtin, can you please provide a quick guideline if you have to post an answer.

Comment: @maRtin Thank you so much of your answer! I will try it out also. Thank you.